# Adding C library to c++11 distutils project

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils, python-packaging

I have a c++11 project that I want to export as a package for use by python scripts. My code uses lzfse C files I download and add to my project.
This project need to compile on both MacOS and Linux.
I created the following setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('car_mechanic',
                    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
                    sources=['car_mechanic_py.cpp', 'png_parse.cpp', 'car_parse.cpp', 'lodepng.cpp', 'logger.cpp'
                             , 'lzfse/src/lzfse_fse_py.c', 'lzfse/src/lzfse_decode_py.c', 'lzfse/src/lzfse_encode_py.c'
                            , 'lzfse/src/lzfse_decode_base_py.c', 'lzfse/src/lzfse_encode_base_py.c'
                            , 'lzfse/src/lzvn_decode_base_py.c', 'lzfse/src/lzvn_encode_base_py.c'])

setup(name='car_mechanic',
       version='1.0',
       description='This package parses and changes the Asset.car ios apps use',
       ext_modules=[module1])
```

Then used `python setup.py build`

There are 2 issues with this solution:

- `-std=c++11` flag doesn't work for .c files under MacOS as it runs clang which doesn't support it. It also issues a warning on Linux
- For each .c file from the lzfse library, I needed to add an `#include <python2.7/Python.h>`. Since I didn't want to change the original files, I created a `lzfse_XXX_py.c` file for every `lsfse_XXX.c`, which does only:

`#include <python2.7/Python.h>
 #include "lzfse_XXX.c"`

any better way to turn lzfse into a library used by my python package? Will Setuptools solve my problems?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pylzfse/ `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dimkr/pylzfse && pip install pylzfse`

Answer (score 0):

using @phd's answer:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dimkr/pylzfse
cd pylzfse
python setup.py build
```

removed all lzfse files from my module, then copied to lzfse.so and imported before importing my module